# Exception handling when executing a sequence of actions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, exception, monads

Here's the gist of the code I am looking to incorporate error handling into.

```
worldHandler :: ProcessState -> JobCount -> IO ()
worldHandler world jCount = do
   putStrLn "Entered worldHandler"
   jcount <- takeMVar jCount
   if jcount > 0
      then incrementThenDone jcount
      else doJobProcessing jcount
      where incrementThenDone jcount = do
                putMVar jCount (jcount+1)


            doJobProcessing jcount = do
                putMVar jCount (jcount+1)
                preProcess world
                initiateJob world
                makeChart world
```

Here's `main`.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    world <- (newEmptyMVar :: IO ProcessState)
    jCount <- (newMVar 0 :: IO JobCount)
    installHandler userDefinedSignal1 (Catch $ worldHandler world jCount) Nothing
    forever (threadDelay 10000)
```

The functions `preProcess`, `initiateJob`, and `makeChart` is where I need
be concerned with errors. The idea is that if any of those functions
fail, I decrement `jCount` and call `logError`. Then if `jCount > 0`, start the same three functions again. If `jCount == 0`, continue waiting for the
next signal.

Each of these functions will be starting another process,
`readProcessWithExitCode` looks like what I want. I will then use the
exit code to determine success or failure.

One idea I had was to make a `[preProcess, initiateJob, makeChart]`.
Then I would map function `jobProcessor` over this list. If one of these
functions received a failure from the program they called, I could
generate an execption, and map would stop mapping over the list.

Is this a sound approach?

General ideas about how to approach this, and any questions that come
to mind would be appreciated.

**Edit:** Due to the first question asked, I re-evaluated my explanation and noted it was incomplete in important ways. I think filled in the blanks. If not, let me know.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here - what does jCount represent? Won't it just keep increasing without bounds?

Comment: No, what's no included in the code is the decrement of jCount upon either job completion or an exception. jCount will keep track of jobs that need processing. If it's > 0 then the increment represents another job. Upon either an exception thrown or a completed job, jCount would be checked again. If > 0 then it goes through the same three processing functions.

Comment: Why do you need to keep track of a count, though? worldHandler knows if it has a job that hasn't finished or not, and I don't see any sort of job queue or thread pool here...

Comment: Perhaps he's using `jCount` as a poor mans [BoundedChan](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/BoundedChan)?

Comment: bdolan: I did that to account for the possibility that a signal may be caught while a job is in progress. It seemed the simplest way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just look at this sequence, laying aside the counting for now.

```
preProcess world
initiateJob world
makeChart world
```

As a top-level function it would look like

```
doJobProcessing :: ProcessState -> IO ()
doJobProcessing world = do
    preProcess world
    initiateJob world
    makeChart world
```

.  We want to interrupt that flow of execution if any of them fails, and (possibly) to restart.

One could use Haskell-exceptions, or not.  Let's look at a solution without exceptions first, because it would work in non-IO code too.  I don't know what your types actually are, so let's suppose they are all

```
preProcess, initiateJob, makeChart :: ProcessState -> IO ExitCode
```

Now here is the horridly ugly obvious way to do it (always a good place to start)

```
doJobProcessing :: ProcessState -> IO ()
doJobProcessing world = do
    preProcessStatus <- preProcess world
    if preProcessStatus /= ExitSuccess
      then jobFail world
      else do
        initiateJobStatus <- initiateJob world
        if initiateJobStatus /= ExitSuccess
          then jobFail world
          else do
            makeChartStatus <- makeChart world
            if makeChartStatus /= ExitSuccess
              then jobFail world
              else return ()  ---success!!!

jobFail :: ProcessState -> IO ()
jobFail world = do
    --some test involving jCount
    if --test says to try again
      then do
        --inc/dec jCount
        doJobProcessing world
      else do
        -- nothing; we give up
        return ()
```

Does that behave how you want?  (If even makeChart fails, it'll try again starting from the beginning at preProcess.)  If it does, then I'll show how it could be simplified with pure Haskell abstractions and/or exceptions.  (If you wanted each of preProcess, initiateJob and makeChart to restart itself only, I'll show a way to do that instead.)